# Can't instantiate alias templates containing lambdas as template arguments in their type-id expression

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following C++20 code:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct TypeWrapper {};

template <auto F>
struct NonTypeWrapper {};

namespace using_value {
    using alias = NonTypeWrapper<42>;

    using user = TypeWrapper<alias>; //Ok
}

namespace using_value_with_template {
    template <bool B>
    using alias = NonTypeWrapper<42>;

    template <bool B>
    using user = TypeWrapper<alias<B>>; //Ok
}

namespace using_lambda {
    using alias = NonTypeWrapper<[] () {}>;

    using user = TypeWrapper<alias>; //Ok
}

namespace using_lambda_with_template {
    template <bool B>
    using alias = NonTypeWrapper<[] () {}>;

    template <bool B>
    using user = TypeWrapper<alias<B>>; //error: template argument 1 is invalid
}
```

(compiler-explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/bWGhn6PWW)

GCC fails to compile this code with the following error:

```
<source>:32:37: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   32 |     using user = TypeWrapper<alias<B>>; //error: template argument 1 is invalid
      |
```

Clang doesn't support lambdas as template arguments yet so I can only use GCC.

Two questions:

1. Is there any reason why one can't instantiate alias templates containing lambdas as template arguments in their type-id expression or is it a GCC bug?
2. Why does GCC print out such an unhelpful message? Shouldn't the compiler at least give us a clue as to why the argument is invalid?

Comment: Actually this work with clang trunk. I'm guessing it's either a bug, or unimplemented feature.

Comment: You're right, I didn't test trunk. For GCC, one workaround is to use a class template with either a non-templated alias or inheritance. I still don't understand why the GCC devs decided not to print out any additional information when such an error occurs (and it can happen for many reasons, this is just one case).